# Retrieving rows based on another column's aggregate values in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query for MS SQL Server which returns the `container_parent_id`s that have quantity of 0:

```
Container_id | Container_name | container_parent_id | quantity | alive
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1            | ContA          | 12345               | 2        | 1
2            | ContB          | 12345               | 1        | 1
3            | ContC          | 12345               | 0        | 1
4            | ContD          | 12345               | 1        | 1
5            | ContA          | 23456               | 1        | 1
6            | ContB          | 23456               | 0        | 1
7            | ContC          | 23456               | 1        | 1
8            | ContD          | 34567               | 0        | 1
9            | ContE          | 34567               | 0        | 1
```

In the above data, only *ContD* and *ContE* should be returned for 34567.

If I group by `container_parent_id` and use `WHERE quanity = 0`, the result includes other rows.

This is what I have been trying:

```
SELECT count(), container_parent_id from Container where quantity = 0 GROUP BY container_parent_id HAVING count() > 0
```

resulting in:

```
3 | ContC | 12345 | 0 | 1 
6 | ContB | 23456 | 0 | 1 
8 | ContD | 34567 | 0 | 1 
9 | ContE | 34567 | 0 | 1
```

Problem with running this query or what Renu/Stan suggested is, it returns those containers that have quantity as 0 - as a subset. But, I do not want the *first two* as they have other containers with quantities 1 or 2 for the same `container_parent_id`. My final output should just be:

```
8 | ContD | 34567 | 0 | 1 
9 | ContE | 34567 | 0 | 1
```

I.e. every container_parent_id that which has only records with quantity = 0.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What have you tried so far? What columns do you want in your results?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Containers
WHERE 
    container_parent_id IN (
        SELECT container_parent_id 
        FROM Containers 
        GROUP BY container_parent_id 
        HAVING sum(quantity) = 0
      );
```

First select all the parent IDs that have a total of 0 quantity and then use that as a nested query to get all the container names that have those IDs as parents.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T.*
FROM Container  t
    INNER JOIN (      
            SELECT container_parent_id,SUM(quantity) Tot
            FROM Container   
            GROUP BY container_parent_id) g ON T.container_parent_id = G.container_parent_id
WHERE G.Tot=0
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply Try this,

```
SELECT container_parent_id FROM Container WHERE quantity=0
```

Comment: And if want to remove duplicates, use `SELECT DISTINCT`